# Spring Doc Open API 3.0 with Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html. After login with credentials and I get the following error

***Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 04 18:13:36 IST 2023
[e390a773-4] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND***

I havent added any Swagger config classes. I have security config class and I have permitted the specific url

My project is MAVEN build. My dependencies related are as follows:

```
<!--                    SpringDoc OPEN API 3.0-->


<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>`


<!--                    REACTIVE-->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
<artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```